# MySQL if exists (select), update, else, insert with python using date comparison

Tags: python, mysql

i am trying to perform a db update on the condition that a db record exists in for multiple columns with values of type DATE in the event that their respective conditions are satisfied, but i appear to be having trouble.  any help is much appreciated.  Thanks!

the following code

```
    select_cmd = "SELECT * FROM " + self.designator + " WHERE player_fkid=" + str(fixed['player_fkid']) + \
                    " AND team_fkid=" + str(fixed['team_fkid']) + " AND season_fkid=" + str(fixed['season_fkid'])

    update_start_cmd = "UPDATE " + self.designator + " SET date_start='" + str(update['date_start']) + \
                    "' WHERE date_start>'" + str(update['date_start']) + "'"

    update_end_cmd = "UPDATE " + self.designator + " SET date_end='" + str(update['date_end']) + "' WHERE date_end<'" + \
                    str(update['date_end']) + "'"

    insert_cmd = "INSERT INTO " + self.designator + " (player_fkid, team_fkid, season_fkid, date_start, date_end) VALUES (" + \
                    str(fixed['player_fkid']) + ", " + str(fixed['team_fkid']) + ", " + str(fixed['season_fkid']) + ", '" + \
                    str(update['date_start']) + "', '" + str(update['date_end']) + "')"

    cmd = "IF EXISTS (" + select_cmd + ")" + "\n" + update_start_cmd + "\n" + update_end_cmd + "\nELSE " + insert_cmd

    try:
        cursor.execute(cmd)
        cnx.commit()
    except mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError:
        print "Error: invalid command '" + cmd + "'"
```

returns the following error:

**Error: invalid command 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM roster WHERE player_fkid=1 AND team_fkid=1 AND season_fkid=1)

UPDATE roster SET date_start='2010-04-13' WHERE date_start>'2010-04-13'

UPDATE roster SET date_end='2010-04-13' WHERE date_end<'2010-04-13'

ELSE INSERT INTO roster (player_fkid, team_fkid, season_fkid, date_start, date_end) VALUES (1, 1, 1, '2010-04-13', '2010-04-13')'**

Comment: i'd like to add that when i execute said statements one by one in the mysql terminal i have no issue.  not sure if the \n is the proper delimiter.

Comment: You can't start a query with `IF EXISTS`.

Comment: What you're looking for is a bit unclear. "update on the condition that a db record exists in for multiple columns with values of type DATE in the event that their respective conditions are satisfied". Could you try to explain that part clearer?

Comment: sure.  sorry about that.  there are two updates to execute in event that if exists condition is satisfied.  execute first update if its conditional statement is satisfied.  execute second udpate if its conditional statement is satisfied.  i've reformatted the error in bold at the bottom to improve readability and to make this more clear.

Comment: @SimeonVisser, thanks!  i've found this solution (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373843/how-to-check-if-record-exists-with-python-mysqdb) for the if exists task.  should i separate my updates into two separate statements to execute, or is there some way to combine these into one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've found that the following works:

```
    cmd = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM roster WHERE player_fkid=" + str(fixed['player_fkid']) + " AND team_fkid=" + str(fixed['team_fkid']) + " AND season_fkid=" + str(fixed['season_fkid'])
    cursor.execute(cmd)
    if cursor.fetchone()[0]:
        udpate_sub_cmd = "UPDATE roster"
        date_start_sub_cmd = "SET date_start= IF(date_start > '" + str(update['date_start']) + "', '" + str(update['date_start']) + "', values(date_start)),"
        date_end_sub_cmd = "date_end= IF(date_end > '" + str(update['date_end']) + "', '" + str(update['date_end']) + "', values(date_end));"
        where_sub_cmd = "WHERE player_fkid=" + str(fixed['player_fkid']) + " AND team_fkid=" + str(fixed['team_fkid']) + " AND season_fkid=" + str(fixed['season_fkid'])
        cmd = udpate_sub_cmd + " " + date_start_sub_cmd + " " + date_end_sub_cmd + " " + where_sub_cmd
        cursor.execute(cmd, multi=True)
    else:
        insert_sub_cmd = "INSERT INTO roster (player_fkid, team_fkid, season_fkid, date_start, date_end)" 
        values_sub_cmd = "VALUES (" + str(fixed['player_fkid']) + ", " + str(fixed['team_fkid']) + ", " + str(fixed['season_fkid']) + ", '" + str(update['date_start']) + "', '" + str(update['date_end']) + "')"
        cmd = insert_sub_cmd + " " + values_sub_cmd
        cursor.execute(cmd)
```

using a portion of the solution from the previously mentioned link.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the [Insert... on duplicate key update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax.
(and specifically, [conditional duplicate key updates](http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2010/1/18/conditional-duplicate-key-updates-with-mysql))

Something like:

```
INSERT INTO roster (player_fkid, team_fkid, season_fkid, date_start, date_end) 
VALUES (1, 1, 1, '2010-04-13', '2010-04-13')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
date_start= IF(date_start > '2010-04-13', '2010-04-13', values(date_start)),
date_end= IF(date_end > '2010-04-13', '2010-04-13', values(date_end));
```

Comment: correction.  i came to find out that ON DUPLICATE KEY would not serve as a solution in this case because the table cannot have unique or primary keys.  this solution therefore results in unwanted redundant entries because no keys are considered duplicates.  the solution i'm currently working with is posted above (for now).  if somehow this can be executed as one statement without adding a new primary key upon which the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE would be leveraged, i am still somewhat curious.